# Coordinate vector of a subspace of $\mathbb{M}_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: vector-spaces

Have

$$\left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} x & y \\ y & x + y \end{matrix} \right) : x,y,\in \mathbb{R}\right \}$$

Which is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{M}_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$.

I was asked

> What is the coordinate vector of $\left ( \begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right )$?

At which point I replied

$$(x,y) = (2,-1)$$

Because

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} x & y \\ y & x + y \end{matrix} \right)=\left ( \begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right )$$

But my answer didn't achieve 100% of the score (it was half-ok).

So what is the correct, full answer supposed to be? Perhaps there are **multiple** coordinate vectors and I only supplied one?

---

**Added:** The basis of this subspace is

$$\left\{  \left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right ) , \left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right )\right \}$$

Comment: No explanation was given?

Comment: @user156384: No. It may have been an error I guess. Just curious if perhaps there were multiple coordinate vectors (can there be?)

Comment: What is the basis you are considering on $\mathbb{M}_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})?$

Comment: The coordinate vector depends on the basis that is being used (and whether you're using a basis of the subspace or of $M_{2,2}(R)$).

Comment: Was there a preliminary question to give a basis for this subspace?

Comment: @user84413: I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I have added the basis. $\left\{  \left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right ) , \left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right )\right \}$

Comment: You appear to have the correct coordinate vector for this basis.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to ask your instructor why you didn't receive full marks.  But my guess would be that they were looking for a full explanation.  Perhaps something like this:

> the coordinate vector of $\pmatrix{2&-1\cr-1&1\cr}$ with respect to the basis $\left\{\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr},\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&1\cr}\right\}$ is $\pmatrix{2\cr-1\cr}$, because
>   $$\pmatrix{2&-1\cr-1&1\cr}=2\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}+(-1)\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&1\cr}\ .$$